# Finding the expression of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^3=K\oplus L$ as $K=Vect(k)$ and $L = Vect(l_1,l_2)$ and $k=(1,2,1)$, $l_1=(1,0,-1)$, $l_2=(-2,1,1)$.

And Supposing that $q$ is the projection on $K$ in parallel to $L$.

The question is what is the expression of the projection $q$ and how can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-2\\2&0&1\\1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
the  transition matrix from the standard basis to the basis $\mathcal B=(k,l_1,l_2)$ and let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T\in \Bbb R^3$ a vector in the standard basis so its components in  $\mathcal B$ are
$$(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3)^T=P^{-1}x$$
and finally we have

$$q(x)=x'_1k$$

**Edit** I used maxima to compute $P^{-1}$ and I found
$$q(x)=\frac14(x_1+x_2+x_3)k$$

Comment: The answer of your book is incorrect since $q(x,y,z)$ should be $\alpha k$ where $\alpha$ is a number depends on $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: the right answer is $q:\begin{cases}  \mathbb{R}^{ 3 }\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{ 3 } \\ (x,y,z)\rightarrow (\dfrac{ x+y+z }{ 4 },\dfrac{ x+y+z }{ 2 },\dfrac{ x+y+z }{ 4 }) \end{cases}$